# How to enter CUDA fortran kernels using PGI Debugger?

Tags: cuda, fortran, pgi

I have tried adding `-g` option in the command line, however, I still can't enter the kernels in PGI Debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a debugger such as cuda-gdb to debug on the device.  PGDBG only supports debugging host code.

Comment: Is there any GUI debugger to debug on the device?

Comment: Personnally I only use the command line, but per: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gdb cuda-gdb integrates with DDD, Emacs, and NSight if you want to use a GUI.  Though, I'm not sure how well Fortran is supported.  There's also DDT and TotalView, but those are for fee products.